# Monitoring cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, monitoring

I have installed 4 Cassandra nodes and i'm looking for a web UI to monitor my casssandra cluster .

Are they any **free** monitoring tool for cassandra with web interface ?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own free monitoring, we do it the following way:

Start Cassandra with the Jodokia JVM and send Cassandra metrics to InfluxDB using Telegraf, see: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/cassandra

Then you can display these metrics on a Grafana dashboard.

Comment: yeah would suggest the same, you can provide metrics with any tool to a monitoring system. have a look at prometheus for example

Answer (score 1):

We have created a set of tools to monitor our clusters that run from command line, it is available [here](https://github.com/Knewton/cassandra-toolbox), for JMX metrics they are also based in Jolokia

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of 2 famous monitoring and visualization tools: Prometheus and Grafana, where there's a Grafana dashboard for cassandra:
https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/5408